# NetBeans: Behaving weirdly by the end of the "evening"

Tags: java, netbeans

There is nothing wrong with my title,but its true.When i run my Java `NetBeans` in the morning, it works fine.But in evening/night (without switching off my lappy/neatbeans), there is little problem.

When i try to run any program, it won't show me the modified Output of my program.
Suppose, in my program say 'A' i have a print statement say print("hi"), and when i change this to: print("bye") and run the program, it will show me "hi" not "bye".
It will show me "bye" at the 2nd run time.

I don't know whether  this question will be closed or something, but this is real.Has anyone experienced any thing like that?Is this beacuse of :

1)My lappy is on from morning till late nignt,can this cause any problem?

2)My `NetBeans` is opened from morning till late night (any memory problems, or something?)

Note: It works fine it the morning time, please help me to find out the bug, it really irritates alot.

**UPDATE:**

Using Windows 7, NB 6.5.1

Comment: What version of NetBeans?  What OS?  We've had no end of fun running under Windows 7 of late.  You could try deleting the cache (under `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\YourVersionOfNetBeans` and delete it's contents. Then do a clean and build

Comment: @MadProgrammer updated. well, will try at night,now its working fine.O.o How come this morning and eve stuff!

Comment: Upgrade to the latest NetBeans (7.2) if you can, that's always a good start.

Comment: @Dukeling i never had any problem with NetBeans 6, i don't know why its creating problems now, i have NB 7, but have to shift full projects and change a lot of references, thats why :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer it started..lol but i can't find that  path :/

Comment: Do you shut down your computer when done for the day, then boot-up in the morning? Alternately, do you access remote resources, and network congestion is problematic in the afternoon; do any other resources on your system run slow in the evening?

Comment: @JeromyFrench yes,i do shut down,no,other resources are just fine,i dont know what is the problem..!

Comment: Just to get the datapoint, try rebooting at lunch today then observe if NetBeans continues its behavior.

Comment: @JeromyFrench I am observing this from last many days.

Comment: So the problem persists with or without a reboot in the middle of the day? If so, that would seem to absolve NetBeans itself. Unless NetBeans has some sort of scheduled process?

Comment: @JeromyFrench nops, no scheduled processes .This behaviour changes, when i start working with some other project, then it runs fine!

Comment: @MadProgrammer please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.Thanks.

Comment: @joeyrohan As requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deleting the cache (under `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\YourVersionOfNetBeans` and delete it's contents.

Then do a clean and build

Answer (score 0):

try to, clean and build After you make any change in your code. You may have changed the auto save option.

The 2 probable causes you mentioned at last are not valid at all.

Comment: I save it manually , and also i din't changed anything,and also, it works fine in the morning.Can you give any reasons?

Comment: The cause seems to be the change in code is not reflected in the executable. At first run the new code is not being compiled.

Comment: Thats what.why?Ok if this is so,why the  change in code is reflected in the executable in the morning?